# Как защитить сайт и сервер от DDOS? Или может есть сервисы какие-нибудь?

Tags: ddos

Как защитить сервер от DDOS? Или же есть специализированные сервисы?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D1%82%20ddos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если следовать нескольким правилам то DDOs можно избежать, советы тут: [Защита от DDOS атак](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1069/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82-ddos-%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba)

Если же вам нужны сервисы по защите то могу посоветовать CloudFlare, но он защитит максимум от 3-4 степени не более. Можете попробовать использовать и платные сервисы, (так-же у CloudFlare есть и платный тариф с более высокой защитой), можете попробовать сервисы по типу ddos-guard.net или же AWS от Amazon.